# NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem. I am trying to draw an image onto a canvas. The image is not from the HTML page, but on a file. Here is the code i use:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "/images/logo.jpg";
this._canvas.drawImage(img, 300, 300);// this is line 14
```

now, here's the problem. This does not seem to work on Firefox and IE10 (I haven't tested yet on other browsers). On Firefox (21) I get:

```
[19:09:02.976] NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available @ file:///D:/Watermellon/scripts/base-classes.js:14
```

and on IE10 i get:

```
SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
base-classes.js, line 14 character 13
```

The files and their directories are:

```
root/index.html  
root/scripts/base-classes.js  
root/images/logo.jpg
```

Now when I change the img.src to a URL (an image from another site) everything works fine, the image draws itself after a delay(for it's get from the url). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that the image isn't loaded yet before you attempt to use it. Try this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    this._canvas.drawImage(img, 300, 300);// this is line 14
};
img.src = "images/logo.jpg";
```

The `src` property is set **after** binding the event because a cached image's `load` event fires immediately (which is a common problem in IE).

And according to your structure, the path to the image would probably be `images/logo.jpg` (removing the first `/`)

Comment: @MarioStoilov Then that means it's not finding the image. So this doesn't actually solve the problem, it just sets it up to work correctly. Try using `img.src = "images/logo.jpg";` - note the `/` I left out at the beginning of the string

Comment: Yeah, I kinda noticed, but deleted my comment before you replied :/. Thx anyway

Comment: Hello I have the same problem with code but the error comes only in the firefox browser. Where as it working in the other all browsers. Is there any special case for firefox. I have tried this code but still did not get any result. If possible please help me.

Answer (score 5):

You need to wait for the image to load before attempting to draw it into a canvas:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "/images/logo.jpg";
img.onload = function () {
  this._canvas.drawImage(img, 300, 300);// this is line 14
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I guess here, is when the resources be available?, but there is a way to confirm that the resources are available, just check 'complete' attribute of the image object.

```
if (img.complete == true){
   // is available.
} else {
   // wait until is ready.
}
```

Also, you can make a merge method with onload event and a delay method that checking both stuff.

```
var img = new Image();
//first attach handler
img.onload = function(e){
   if (e.target.complete == true) {
            yourHandler(e);
        } else {               
            var maxTimes = 10;
            var countTimes = 0;
            function retryLoadImage() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (countTimes > maxTimes) {
                        // -- cannot load image.
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (e.target.complete == true) {
                            yourHandler(e);
                        } else {
                            retryLoadImage();
                        }
                    }
                    countTimes++;
                }, 50);
            }; 
        }
};
img.src = yourSource;
```

This is working for me!!! on IE and FF.