# Capture a div and save as jpeg

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas

`#cap` is a div i want to capture. 
I used `ctx.drawImage($('#cap').get(0),0,0,640,480);window.open(canvas.getDataURL('image/jpeg'));`

got a `Type error`
and how do i send it to php to save as `a.jpeg`

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/3qNJB/ is not working help `html2canvas is not a function`

Answer (score 5):

**< DIV >** elements cannot be drawn on canvas using  **drawImage()** method.Have a look at [Html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library

**Example:**

```
 html2canvas(document.getElementById('DivToCapture'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
         // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
       window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
     }
  });
```

Heres the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qNJB/2/)

Comment: Note that html2canvas will not capture any cross-domain image elements from the div.

Comment: Yeah it wont work with cross domain image elements......but a workaround to that would be to use a proxy.

Comment: The fiddle you provided had broken link for html2canvas library....Heres a working version. http://jsfiddle.net/3qNJB/2/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the image with javascript, just POST it to your server so PHP can receive it, save it on the server, and then send it back to the browser.

I found this `DivsToJPG()` function here: [Convert html div having multiple images to single image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549338/convert-html-div-having-multiple-images-to-single-image-using-javascript)

```
var DivsToJPG = function( parent ) {
    this.canvasSizeX = 0;
    this.canvasSizeY = 0;
    this.init = function( parent ) {
        this.images = parent.find('img');
        this.setSizes();
        this.createCanvas();
        this.drawImages();
        this.exportJPG();
    }

    this.setSizes = function() {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.images.length; i < l ; i++) {
            var currentImage = this.images.eq(i);
            var posX = currentImage.position().left;
            var width = currentImage.width();
            this.canvasSizeX = this.canvasSizeX > (posX+width) ? this.canvasSizeX : posX + width;
            //console.log(this.canvasSizeX);
            var posY = currentImage.position().top;
            var height = currentImage.height();
            this.canvasSizeY = this.canvasSizeY > (posY+height) ? this.canvasSizeY : posY + height;

         }
    }

    this.createCanvas = function() {
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.canvas.id     = "exportCanvas";
        this.canvas.width  = this.canvasSizeX;
        this.canvas.height = this.canvasSizeY;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    }

    this.drawImages = function() {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.images.length; i < l ; i++) {
            var currentImage = this.images[i];
            var $currentImage = this.images.eq(i);
            this.ctx.drawImage(currentImage, $currentImage.position().left, $currentImage.position().top, $currentImage.width(), $currentImage.height());
        }
    }

    this.exportJPG = function() {
        var dataURL = this.canvas.toDataURL();
        this.img = document.createElement('img');
        this.img.id = "createdImage";
        this.img.src     = dataURL;
        document.body.appendChild(this.img);
    }

    this.init( parent );
}

var divsToJPG = new DivsToJPG($('#cap'));

$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url  : "make-image.php",
  data : { 
     imgBase64 : divsToJPG
  }
}).done(function(data) {

});
```

Then in PHP

```
$img = base64_decode($_POST['imgBase64']);
```

Comment: But cant create image either

Comment: .toDataURL will fatal fail if asked to encode cross-domain images.  Perhaps the best workaround is to (1) have the page upload the html & css to the server, (2) have the server download the cross-domain images to itself, (3) use a "headless browser" on the server to load the received html & css, (4) save the page as an image.  PhantomJS is a good headless browser...or just use SnagIt to capture the screen :-)