# Easeljs game project

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I'm working on a game project but I have a a problem i received this error:

```
NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:

ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0); //Bitmap.js in Easeljs lib.
```

I used the bitmap in the next codes. Please tell me if in this there is a problem and how to fix it.
Thanks for collaboration.

**Code 1**:

```
p.initialize = function(x,y ,stage, world){
    var bmp = new Bitmap('../assets/blackBall.png'); 
    //console.log(bmp)
    //alert(bmp)
    bmp.regX = radius;
    bmp.regY = radius;
    bmp.x=x;
    bmp.y=y;
    this.skin = bmp;

    stage.addChild(bmp);

    var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef();
    fixDef.density = 1.0;
    fixDef.friction = 0.5;
    fixDef.restitution = 0.8;
    fixDef.shape = new b2CircleShape(38*CONST.pixelToMeter);

    var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();

    bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = bmp.x*CONST.pixelToMeter; 
    bodyDef.position.y = bmp.y*CONST.pixelToMeter;

    this.body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
    this.body.CreateFixture(fixDef);
    this.skin.body = this.body;
    setUserData(this.body);
    /*Event handler*/
    this.skin.onMouseOver = handleMouseOver;
    this.skin.onMouseOut = handleMouseOut;
    this.skin.onPress = handleMouseDown;
    //console.log(this.skin);
}
```

**Code 2**:

```
p.initialize = function(stage, world){
    var shooterSkin = new Container();
    var cirlceSkin = new createjs.Bitmap('../assets/shooter.png');
    cirlceSkin.name = "ball";
    var arrowSkin  = new createjs.Bitmap('../assets/arrow.png');
    arrowSkin.name = "arrow";
    arrowSkin.rotation = 0;
    arrowSkin.scaleX =0;
    arrowSkin.regY = arrowHeight;
    cirlceSkin.regX = skinRadius;
    cirlceSkin.regY = skinRadius;
    cirlceSkin.x =0;
    cirlceSkin.y = 0;
    cirlceSkin.alpha=circleAlpha;
    shooterSkin.x=110
    shooterSkin.y = 110;
    shooterSkin.addChild(cirlceSkin);
    shooterSkin.addChild(arrowSkin); 
    arrowIndex = 1;

    this.skin = shooterSkin;
    stage.addChild(shooterSkin);

    var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef();
    fixDef.friction = 0;
    fixDef.restitution = 0;
    fixDef.isSensor = true;
    fixDef.shape = new b2CircleShape(radius*CONST.pixelToMeter);

    var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_kineticBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = shooterSkin.x*CONST.pixelToMeter; 
    bodyDef.position.y = shooterSkin.y*CONST.pixelToMeter;
    this.body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
    this.body.CreateFixture(fixDef);
    setUserData(this.body);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NS\_ERROR\_NOT\_AVAILABLE: Component is not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049176/ns-error-not-available-component-is-not-available)

Comment: I try it but I had the same error. Could you show me your version so I can compare what will be the error? Thanks - @olsn

Comment: Instead of `new createjs.Bitmap('../assets/shooter.png');` load the image first `var img = new Image(); img.onload = create bitmap here...; img.src = '../assets/ect...jpg';` - have you tried that?

Comment: I try it and I receive now this error:                 child.isVisible is not a function
if (!child.isVisible() || !child.mouseEnabled) { continue; } //Container.js line 473 Any idea why?? Thanks - @olsn

Comment: The new update uploaded [link](http://jaketesting.altervista.org/) - @olsn

Comment: I don't want to sound rude now, but this: `var cirlceSkin = new Image(); cirlceSkin.onload = function () { new createjs.Bitmap(); cirlceSkin.src = '../assets/shooter.png'; }` looks to me like you have zero clue what you are doing ;) - I suggest you take a look at how the `onload()`-method actually works. That is part of the JavaScript basics, that you should know. Alternatively you could take a look at PreloadJS. We all started out small at one point, however if you want to build something of that size without knowing the basics, you should be prepared to figure stuff out yourself.