# Javascript image loader fails in Firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, preloader

I am preloading images in Javascript, and it works great in Chrome, IE and Safari, but fails in Firefox with the following error:
"NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:"

I'm using the following function to load images:

```
function loadImages(sources, callback) {
  var loadedImages = 0;
  var numImages = 0;
  // get num of sources
  for(var src in sources) {
    numImages++;
  }
  for(var src in sources) {
    images[src] = new Image();
    images[src].onload = function() {
      if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    images[src].src = sources[src];
  }}
```

And I set up the image array and call the image loader like this:

```
var sources = {
  blockBorder0: 'images/BlockBorder_1.jpg',
  blockBorder1: 'images/BlockBorder_2.jpg' };
loadImages(sources, startRender);
```

Why does it fail on Firefox when it works great on all the other browsers? I put some debug statements out to the console and I see the for loop loading all of the images in Firefox.

Comment: this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049176/ns-error-not-available-component-is-not-available didn't help?

Comment: maybe firefox has troubles resolving the url? Just making that up.

Comment: No @caramba. Same issues seem to happen on that link for people using Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If I change callback() to callback.apply(), it works in Firefox.