# Data does not insert into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json.net

Data suppose to be inserted into database but it does not. JQuery alert failed action before any process. I think the url does not send request to controller at all, Could anyone tell me where is the error in this code.

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController {
    static EmpRepository repository = new EmpRepository();
    public string AddEmployee(Employee em) {
        var response = repository.AddEmployees(em);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Jquery:

```
function AddEmp() {

    var Emp = {};
    Emp.FirstName = $("#fname").val();
    Emp.LastName = $("#lname").val();
    Emp.Company = $("#company").val();

    $.ajax({
        url = 'api/AddEmployee';
        tpye: "post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(Emp),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },

        error: function(x, e){
            alert('Failed');
            alert(x.response);
            //alert(x.status);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#save").click(function (e){
        AddEmp();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: I am wondering why someone marks down the question without any reason !!!

Comment: why you dont add your url to $.ajax call?

Comment: :), you edited your code?

Comment: still not work? i asking because my answer is seems so silly now :D

Comment: What response do you get in the alerts? Have you tired debugging this on the server for 1. finding out if action is actually getting hit by your ajax 2. to   step through your server code to find out what is going on?

Comment: i am getting this error `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: alert('Failed');` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one hour of debugging and testing an error was found  in url, it was not in right format, the right format is `url = 'api/Employee/AddEmployee';`

Comment: thank you for answer. but this is not answer. nobody can guess what is your url :)

Comment: you should also check that huge typo in `contentType: "spplicstion/json;charset=utf-8"`

Comment: That is true, but the main error was the url and that why I posted controller class here.

Answer (score 1):

```
function AddEmp() {

var Emp = {};

 url = 'api/AddEmployee';
Emp.FirstName = $("#fname").val();
Emp.LastName = $("#lname").val();
Emp.Company = $("#company").val();

$.ajax({

    tpye: "post",
    url:url,
    contentType: "spplicstion/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(Emp),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (response) {

        alert(response);
    },

    error: function(x, e){
        alert('Failed');
        alert(x.response);
        //alert(x.status);
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{

$("#save").click(function (e){
    AddEmp();
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: it shows this error `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: alert('Failed');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049176/ns-error-not-available-component-is-not-available

Comment: so do you think error somewhere else? not in Jquery

Comment: try this, put full address of your site in url, url of ajax call

Comment: it did not work, the request does not passe to controller at all, I even tried the url in browser but it does not work.

Comment: Please look at my answer