# Django download and display an image via ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am trying to create an ajax request to my views.py that returns a cropped segment of a larger image. The problem that I am having is that the image doesn't seem to be downloaded, or at least isn't being drawn. There isn't an error message associated with it, just nothing happens (including "test" not being logged to the console).  I have left a few of my attempts with the javascript in but none of them seemed to work.

The view function also doesn't appear to be particularly rapid with the 'called' response being printed 5+ seconds after the request. I am wondering if this is because it takes a long time to load the image? If this is the case is there a way to speed this up i.e. to only load the image once and keep it in memory or just a better way of doing it. It is quite a large image (12000x6000px, 28.5 MB JPEG).
I know that the views.py function is being called by confirming it with the logging module.

So in short:

1. Why is my image not being displayed?
2. Is there a quicker way of delivering the image?

Views.py:

```
def test(request):
    img = Image.open(settings.STATIC_PATH + 'geogame/big_map.jpg')
    img.load()
    xpos = int(request.GET.get('xpos', ''))
    ypos = int(request.GET.get('ypos', ''))
    upper = ypos*10 - 300
    left = xpos*10 - 600
    right = xpos*10 + 600
    lower = ypos*10 + 300
    cropped_img = img.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
    logging.warn('called')

    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'image/jpg')
    img.save(response, "JPEG")
    return response
```

Ajax request:

```
Game.zoom = function() {
    zoomx = Game.clickX
    zoomy = Game.clickY
    $.ajax({
        url: 'zoom/',
        data: {xpos: zoomx, ypos: zoomy},
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            //Game.zoomedImg.src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+data
            //Game.zoomedImg.src = data;
            //console.log(Game.zoomedImg.src);
            Game.zoomedImg.onload = function() {
                console.log("load");
                Game.zoomedImg.src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+data
            }
            //$("#" + this.zoomedImg).one("load", function() {
            //    console.log("test");
            //    Game.ctx.drawImage(Game.zoomedImg, 0, 0);
            //    }).attr("src", "data:image/jpg;base64,"+data);
            //Game.ctx.drawImage(Game.zoomedImg, 0, 0);
            console.log("hello");
            //};
        },
        failure: function(data) {
            console.log('failed to load zoomed image')
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()     logging.warn('egege')
cropped_img.save(buffer, format = "JPEG")
logging.warn('ffgge')
img_str = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
logging.warn('leflefe')
return HttpResponse(img_str)
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more details. What is Game? What is the `zoom` event? When does it get called? Why have you assigned the returned data within an `onload` event - what would trigger that?

Comment: Game is a class (I think, I am pretty new javascript). zoom is called on upon a user clicking on a html5 canvas, those coordinates are used to do the zoom. The data was assigned to an onload event because I have read that you don't want to assign the src until it has been fully downloaded and this doesn't get activated until this occurs (I could be wrong). However I am fairly certain the onload function is not called at all.

Comment: But the data *is* loaded, because you are inside the Ajax success function which doesn't trigger until response finishes loading. It really doesn't make sense to use onload there.

Comment: hmmm, removing the onload function introduces a NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE error though, That is where I read about using the onload function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049176/ns-error-not-available-component-is-not-available

Comment: You need to base64 encode the image for the response. Otherwise you will just have a big binary string in your ajax response.

Comment: I've tried to base64 encode it but I just keep getting internal server errors, any ideas? I have shown my attempts in the edit above!

Comment: I have managed to base64 encode the image as detailed in the edit above, however I am getting an error from my return statement for some reason, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe I have solved both parts

The image needs to be loaded into a string buffer and base64 encoded to be downloaded after being loaded like so:

```
buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
cropped_img.save(buffer, format = "JPEG")
img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
return HttpResponse(img_str)
```

This is seemingly because the crop action is lazy and needs to be saved before it takes effect.

Also to speed up the process the image load operation and make it a single occurence the following two lines can be moved to the beginning of the views.py file OUTSIDE of the function.

```
img = Image.open(settings.STATIC_PATH + 'geogame/big_map.jpg')
img.load()
```